# How to get OAuth client key and client secret to android app at runtime without hard-coding

Tags: php, android, wordpress, oauth

I need to find a way to authorize an android client with a wordpress API at runtime using OAuth, without hard-coding the client key and client secret.

I added a new application in wordpress and generated a client key and client secret. In addition to that, I installed the "Wordpress REST API - OAuth1.0a Server" Plugin.

As for now, the client key and secret is hard-coded inside of my android project. I successfully authorized my android client with these credentials using OAuth1.0a and can make requests to the API.

However, **multiple** android clients should be able to connect to **different** wordpress API's.
After the app is **build only once**, a client should have the ability to get the client key and secret for a specific Wordpress site to initiate an OAuth authorization.
Therefore, the client key and secret need to be specified somehow during the initial setup process at runtime.
Is there a better to do this, other than manually typing in the client key and secret?
I really feel like I'm overlooking something quite obvious, but couldn't find the answer yet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess the practice is to declare the default in `gradle.properties` then override them with environment variables. Please read [this article](https://medium.com/@rafamatias/gradle-android-build-variables-done-right-d0c0e296ee93) for details.

Comment: Thank you for the article, it is quite interesting but in my understanding this approach only works at build time, but I need to do it at runtime.